# SQL Update row values from another row if value does not match

Tags: sql, ssms

SQL rookie here. I'm trying to update a specific row of values using values from  another row in the same table. However, I want the initial values to only update if it's null or does not match the new value.

My current unfinished script:

```
DECLARE @Record1 VARCHAR(50) = 'ID1', 
        @Record2 VARCHAR(50)='ID2'

UPDATE R1
SET r1.column1 = COALESCE(r1.column1, r2.column1),
    r1.column2 = COALESCE(r1.column2, r2.column2),
    r1.column3 = COALESCE(r1.column3, r2.column3),
    r1.column4 = COALESCE(r1.column4, r2.column4)
FROM TABLE1 r1 
INNER JOIN TABLE1 r2 ON r1.ID1 = @Record1 AND r2.ID2 = @Record2
```

I'm currently using SQL Server 2016 Management Studio.

EDIT:

After reading Sgeddes's reply, I realize my question was very dumb. Of course replacing everything in Record1 from Record2 makes the most sense.

I guess what I was fishing for was if there way a way to place a condition on each column to update. For example, if I wanted to update Record1's columns 1 & 2 only if NULL, but replace everything in columns 3 & 4 from Record2.

Comment: Remove `coalesce` and always update to `r2.column`.  It will update all records, those that match will just be the same value...

Answer (score 0):

You would use a `left join` . . . carefully:

```
UPDATE R1
    SET r1.column1 = coalesce(r1.column1, r2.column1),
        r1.column2 = coalesce(r1.column2, r2.column2),
        r1.column3 = coalesce(r1.column3, r2.column3),
        r1.column4 = coalesce(r1.column4, r2.column4)
    FROM TABLE1 r1 LEFT JOIN
         TABLE1 r2 
         ON r2.ID2 = @Record2
    WHERE r1.ID1 = @Record1 ;
```

Note that the condition on `r1` goes in the `where` clause so it actually filters rows.  The condition on `t2` stays in the `on` clause, so all rows are returned, even when there are no matches in `r2`.